# Using external permalinks in Jekyll markdown

Tags: markdown, jekyll, github-pages

How can I include permalinks in my Jekyll blog?

I've tried setting the URL as a variable and then using that, but the result is still just that is uses my current site URL:

```
[apigee]: https://apigee.com

API Console]({{apigee}}/embed/console/instagram)
```

Doing the above just outputs as `http://myURL.com/embed/console/instagram`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to access your variable as a `page` attribute

```
---
apigee: 'https://apigee.com'
---

[API Console][the_link]

[the_link]: {{page.apigee}}/embed/console/instagram
```

will work just fine.